# Can this system of equations have unique solutions?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have the equation:

$$c=z[\sin(x)\sin(2\pi yt)-\cos(x)\cos(2\pi yt)]$$

Where $c$ has three known values, each of which is followed by a value for $t$. Therefore one can be left with a system of three equations with three unknowns. Can this system have unique values ?

In other words, can the system:

$$c_1=z[\sin(x)\sin(2\pi yt_2)-\cos(x)\cos(2\pi yt_2)]$$

$$c_3=z[\sin(x\sin(2\pi yt_3)-\cos(x)\cos(2\pi yt_3)]$$

Where $c_1,c_2,c_3,t_1,t_2,t_3$ are all known be solved with unique 
solutions ?

The values can be obtained with the help of a computer, no need to solve it manually, just want to know if it has unique solutions

Comment: Can write more compactly as
$$c_j = -z\cos \left (x+2\pi yt_j\right ) $$
For arbitrary input parameters a solution need not be unique, for instance
$$z\cos (x+y2\pi) = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

If the system has solutions, they are non-unique since $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are periodic, so if $x$ is a solution, so is $x+2k\pi,k\in\Bbb Z$.